# Powershell Script help - Add User and Copy Permissions from Folder

Tags: powershell

I've tried around a bit, but haven't come up with a good result yet. My powershell skills are also a bit rusty.

What do I have in mind?

I want to read all security groups from a folder. For each security group I search in a domain (Active Directory) for the group and get all users contained in it.
Afterwards I add the user with the same rights again extra to the folder.
Reason: I search for the group or the user in another domain. Both domains are accessible from the same server. The groups will be removed at some point.

How can I do this? I have already tried a bit to read out groups (Get-Acl) etc, but I do not get further.

I do not ask for a complete solution, but just need hints how I could do this. Possibly also how this is then called in Powershell etc.

Comment: You can't bypass asking a question just by saying "I do not ask for a complete solution, but just need hints how I could do this". What exactly did you try, and where did you get stuck? :)

Comment: OK. 
So, I dont have the script now, but I tried to get the access rule of an group and had no luck with it. 

1. I get all Folders and foreach loop them
2. Get all Security Groups (custom) for each folder
3. foreach loop every Security Group and (try) to get the Access rules. (did not work)
4. remember access rule
5. search for all users in ad and to a foreach loop for every user
6. add user with access rule above (how to i do this?)

Comment: Better add the users to security groups and give the **groups** permissions on the folders. That will make administering your AD environment a lot easier because then you only have to add or remove users from a group and you do not have to constantly adjust NTFS permissions.

Comment: @Theo I know, but the customer wants it that way .-) I told them the other way would be better, but they have some rules they got from the government.

Comment: Hmpf.. government rules.. That immediately blocks all practicality ;)